# Aspectj inside transaction - don't save log on roll back

Tags: java, transactions, aspectj, rollback

Let's say it's schema of my code:

One class:

```
@Transactional
public void mainMethod(){
   // do smth 1
   addSmthToDatabase();
   // do smth 2
}
```

Second class:

```
public void logAdd() {
   //save what's addedd
}
```

On method addSmthToDatabase() aspect is added. After returning from addSmthToDatabase() method logAdd is called which saves what was added to databse. 
It works ok when transaction is commited. But when smth goes wrong in "do smth 2" transaction is rolled back so nothing is added to database. But log is still saved. How can I fix it?

Comment: How about logging the whole transaction (`@Transactional void mainMethod()`) when it is clear that it was successful?

Comment: The problem is, addSmthToDatabase() isn't called every time. Execution of this method depends on some data, so sometimes this method will be called (log should be saved) and sometimes not (log shouldn't be saved).

Comment: Then log both the event changing the database and the rollback, if any. Or only log on commit. If you log something which might get rolled back later later, maybe you log too early. Keep it simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it's possible to rollback aspectj method too. But seems it's not, so I'll change it to log on main method.

Comment: What do you mean by "to roll back a method"? You cannot un-execute a method or un-log a message. But a good RDBMS supports transactions by design, this is a totally different category from logging. ;-)